# How to order by multiple fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

I'm looking to order data in a specific way where I have explicitly laid out which fields I want to appear first. Basically, I'm looking to return a MySQL query by doing something that I would imagine might look like this:

```
ORDER BY
  FIELD(brand,'toyota','honda','ford'),
  FIELD(type, 'SUV', 'Sedan', 'Coupe'),
  FIELD(transmission, 'manual', 'automatic', 'cvt')
```

Simply said I'm looking for a way to order things specifically based on multiple fields. I've tried it like this but it doesn't seem to be working. Can this even be done or after I specify the order of one field do I have to only order other things by either ASC or DESC?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to show how it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT brand, type, transmission      
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY 
 case brand
  when 'toyota' then 1
  when 'honda' then 2
  when 'ford' then 3
 end ASC,
 case type
  when 'SUV' then 1
  when 'Sedan' then 2
  when 'Coupe' then 3
 end ASC,
 case transmission
  when 'manual' then 1
  when 'automatic' then 2
  when 'cvt' then 3
 end ASC
```

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/17288